# invalid object in oracle

Tags: oracle

When I try to compile this package body

```
PROCEDURE send (
    p_rtOldData_i IN AAA_AIRPORTPARAMETERS%ROWTYPE,
    p_rtNewData_i IN AAA_AIRPORTPARAMETERS%ROWTYPE,
    p_sProducer_i IN VARCHAR2 := USER,
    p_iPriority_i IN PLS_INTEGER := EVMTransport.m_cnDefPriority
  );
```

I get the following error :

> Object name EVMTransport.m_cnDefPriority is invalid

I need to know what to do, what does this means and how could this be resolved?

Comment: What is mean by EVMTransport.m_cnDefPriority

Comment: i dont know , its an imported database

Comment: `select owner, object_name, object_type, status from all_objects where upper(name) in ('EVMTRANSPORT', 'M_CNDEFPRIORITY');` what do you get back? if its a package spec / function, try to compile it and show us the compilation error(s)

Comment: If `EVMTransport.m_cnDefPriorit` is a type, is the type definition valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If EVMTransport is a package it means it is invalid.
Try recompile this package and solve the errors if any.

Comment: ok , anyways if it is another schema , how can i make it visible for other users ? can i make the schema -public , so that all it s tables , triggers etc are visible to other schema users ?